# bash script. how to do output redirection with here documents

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I am running a c program using here documents because the c program expects inputs from the user.

so i have something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
./runnable inputfile.txt <<_END_
2
4
3
4
3
3
2
_END_
```

now i want to send the output from the above command to some other file. 
just like we would do

```
ls > file.txt
```

is that possible?

Comment: Just curious: why haven't you just tried this? Seems like little trouble to do so...

Comment: Very little trouble indeed. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can simply do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
./runnable inputfile.txt <<_END_ > file.txt
2
4
3
4
3
3
2
_END_
```